# WL.Server.invokeProcedure() is not working on Rest end point

Tags: rest, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, worklight-adapters

I'm using SQL adapter using which I'm trying to invoke another adapter procedure, But I'm getting connection timeout error. This occurs when I call adapter using rest end point.

The following is my code

`function test(){
    WL.Logger.info("Test Method")
    return WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
        adapter : "AnotherTestAdapter",
        procedure : "anotherTestProcedure",
        parameters : []
  })
}`

This is the endpoint I have given

> http://domain:port/context/adapters/mainAdapter/test

I'm getting the "Test Method" printed and after that connection is getting timed out.

But when I call invoke method, I got success response

> http://domain:port/context/invoke?adapter=mainAdapter&parameters=[]&procedure=test

Comment: Can you provide a project with an where this works and where this fails? We could then debug it.

Comment: @IdanAdar: When I tried a dummy project and copied same code to the new project, then its working fine. Actually, I don't know why it's behaving like this.